# Upload files with Ajax - FormData

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

First of all, i search in many many topics about that and i dont want to use any plugins.

```
function addToDatabase(menuItem){
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("Description", document.getElementById("DescriptionID").value);
  jQuery.each($('#filesID')[0].files, function(i, file) {
      formData.append('file-'+i, file);
  });

  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "dbAdder.php",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(result){
      $("#PageContent").html(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Js function that sending to server things. While in the server-side code `$_POST['Description']` have value, but `$_FILES['file-0']` doesnt.

```
<input type="file" id="filesID" name="files[]" multiple />
<textarea id="DescriptionID" rows="5" cols="53"></textarea>
```

HTML part of code.

Comment: There is no comfortable solution. Every file-upload-via-Ajax involves hacks such as iFrames. What issue do you have with each individual plugin? Chances are that you will have the same issues without the plugin.

Comment: Because i am not sure how plugins works, if the owner of plugin have access to my data before i send it to my server. And that code will see only the moderators of Database of original webpage.

Comment: Then go read about how jQuery plugins work before you dismiss them.

Comment: Are you sure you want to `.append()` if you can simply define `new FormData(document.getElementById('form'))` as a data to be sent?

Comment: In your PHP script, that should be `$_FILES['files']`, not `$_FILES['file-0']`

Comment: @DaveJust i try it, even if i dont see logic at it. Check this line of code `jQuery.each($('#filesID')[0].files, function(i, file) {
      formData.append('file-'+i, file);
  });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are planning to upload files, it complicates it all a little bit.

if external plugin is not an option, i highly suggest using XHR2.

it's pure javascript, and deals well with file uploads.

BUT- note that it's not supported by all browsers, see here: http://caniuse.com/xhr2

```
// prepare xhr object
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', 'dbAdder.php', true);

// upload complete handler
xhr.onload = function(e){
if (this.status == 200) {
    //
}
    else { // }
};

// upload progress handler
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
            // e.total, e.loaded
    }
};

var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("file", file);
fd.append("Description", 'description text');
fd.append("field2", 'value2');

// send the xml http request
xhr.send(fd);
```

here's a very nice tutorial for further use of xhr2: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

hope that helps

Comment: Do i have to include something like `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>` this?

Comment: yes, it can handle multipart/form-data (files & strings as you call it). and no, as i said, pure javascript, no external plugins needed.

Comment: In `fd.append("file", file);` in variable of `file` i have to put image source?

Comment: no, `file` is the file object itself (straight from fileinput)

Comment: If i have `<input type="file" id="filesID" name="files[]" multiple />` what i have to set into `file`? And how i can read server response?

Comment: server response returns at `xhr.onload` handler.

Comment: `file` should be `document.getElementById('filesID').files[0]` for example

Comment: Same results :( $_POST['Description'] getting value but $_FILES['file'] dont. – Crackeraki 6 hours ago